# Should we make the [significado] tag a synonym to the [semântica] one?

Tags: discussion

In the context of tags I see no difference - or is there a relevant distinction I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe there's a... semantic difference. Haha! ;)

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Hahhaha... yeah, sure they are not synonyms per se, but for classifying questions I wonder if there is any relevant difference.

Comment: :) I share your opinion that for classification purposes the difference is small enough to justify not having them separate.